# Azure AD Enterprise apps, assigning users

Tags: azure-active-directory

i want to validate my understanding here.

I have an web application and register this app in Azure AD. In Enterprise applications, i assign a set of users to the app without granting consent for that users.
-> If that users login to the app, will that work? I think not, as no consent is granted. From my understanding, every user has to grant consent to the app (depending on what the app requires) or an admin has to grant consent for all users.

I heard something different, that it is enough to just add the users to the app. So please shed some light on that:)

BR
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

> In Enterprise applications, i assign a set of users to the app without granting consent for that users. -> If that users login to the app, will that work? I think not, as no consent is granted.

By default, even though you don't grant consent for the users, the users can still log in to the app. 
[image]

Without any granting, the user can sign in and the app can read user profile, and this not requires admin.